# How to get strptime with Python in german notation?

Tags: python

I am receiving a datetime with Pyhton 3. of this format:

```
23. Mär 2018 08:00:02
```

The month is in German notation and stands for March. While trying to convert it to a datetime object I do get an error. Months like Feb work which are of same naming as in eng.

```
dt.datetime.strptime(result['postedDateTime'], '%d. %b %Y %H:%M:%S').strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
```

Is there a way to configure strptime for german notation?

Comment: Briefly: set the desired locale.

Comment: If you're computer is configured for Germany, call `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')` before using `strptime()`. If not, call `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'german_germany')`.

Comment: The locale might be 'de_DE'.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed it for me: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "de_DE")